# Using JwtAuthProviderReader with ServiceStack and AWS Cognito

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-auth

We are using an existing userpool in **AWS Cognito**, a separate client app is created for our api server.

When using the hosted UI from Cognito **accessToken**, **idToken** and **refreshToken**.

The issue is when adding **JwtAuthProviderReader** to **AuthFeature** for doing the token validation we get "**HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized**" for any endpoint we create with the [Authenticate] attribute.

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
  new IAuthProvider[]
  {
    new JwtAuthProviderReader
    {
      Audience = "11rqr096c55xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", // App client id
      Issuer = "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/eu-west-1_xxXxxXXxX",
      HashAlgorithm = "RS256",
      PublicKey = new RSAParameters
      {
        Modulus = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes("JRDU3q2XoOcKGjcj1DsJ3Xj .... DTNVCGzUCGosKGYL0Q"),
        Exponent = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes("AQAB")
      },
      RequireSecureConnection = false,          
    }
  }
)
{ 
  IncludeAssignRoleServices = false
});
```

The modulus and Exponent is from **e** and **n** in Well-Known response ref https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/eu-west-1_xxXxxXXxX/.well-known/jwks.json

Service protected by Authenticate attribute always returns **HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized**

```
[Authenticate]
public object Get(GetTenants request)
{
   return ...;
}
```

How can we know that our **JwtAuthProviderReader** is setup correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test whether your JWT can be validated with ServiceStack's [JWT Auth Provider](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) by testing the JWT Token in the `IsJwtValid` API of a configured `JwtAuthProviderReader` instance, e.g:

```
var jwtAuth = new JwtAuthProviderReader { ... };
jwtAuth.IsJwtValid(jwt);
```

This will return `false` if the JWT is not valid. There's a lot of reasons why a JWT wouldn't be valid, so the first thing I'd check is to test you can actually decrypt the JWE Token by calling `GetVerifiedJwePayload()`, e.g:

```
var jsonObj = jwtAuth.GetVerifiedJwePayload(null, jwt.Split('.'));
```

If successful it will return a decrypted but unverified JSON Object. This will fail with your current configuration because decrypting an RSA JWE Token requires configuring the complete `PrivateKey`, i.e. not just the `PublicKey` components.

If you're only using RSA256 to verify the JWT Signature instead of encrypting the JWE Token and `jwtAuth.IsJwtValid(jwt)` returns `false`, you can verify if signature is valid by calling `GetVerifiedJwtPayload()`, e.g:

```
var jwtBody = jwtAuth.GetVerifiedJwtPayload(null, jwt.Split('.'));
```

This will return `null` if the signature verification failed otherwise it will return a `JsonObject` with the contents of the JWT Body.

You can then validate the jwtBody payload to check if the JWT is valid, e.g:

```
var invalidErrorMessage = jwtAuth.GetInvalidJwtPayloadError(jwtBody);
var jwtIsValid = invalidErrorMessage == null;
```

Which returns `null` if the JWT is valid otherwise a string error message why it's not.

Comment: Since we're using RS256 there is only PublicKey part.

jwtAuth.IsJwtValid(jwt) returns true, but jwtAuth.GetVerifiedJwePayload(null, jwt.Split('.')) throws exception: IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @Kai-Rune you need the private key to be able to decrypt a JWE Token which has 5 parts, but doesn't sound like you're using JWE. How many parts does `jwt.Split('.').Length` have? 5 or 3? and are you able to decode your JWT in https://jwt.io ?

Comment: It´s 3 parts, and jwt.io says "Signature Verified". 
I can´t use GetVerifiedJwePayload to verify the token, since it´s JWS and not JWE

Comment: @Kai-Rune ok then it's only using RSA256 for verifying the JWT signature. See my updated answer above of other APIs to call to test & validate the JWT.