# ServiceStack API aspnet core with Azure AD B2C returns 401 for request even with bearer token

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack

I have a working ServiceStack API that authenticates against a AzureAD tenant.  We are trying to move this to start using Azure B2C.  The application is build with c# and runs on net 5.0. I've managed to change the configuration to use the 'correct' config.  I'm then using Postman to get my access token from my tenant suing the authorization code flow.

However, when i make a request to the api, the response is always a 401 status code.

Where in the servicestack code can I put a break point to see why this failure is happening?  I have tried multiple places in our AppHostConfigurator.cs/AppHost.cs files, but the break points doesn't appear to display why a 401 is being sent back as a response.  I'm sure it's something related to wrong claims/roles expected etc, maybe the Azure ADB2C application being setup incorrectly, but obviously i need to know exactly so that i can resolve.

I'm setting up the authentication like this:

```
    private static void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppHost host)
    {
        var authProviders = new List<IAuthProvider> {new NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider(host.AppSettings)};

        if (host.AppSettings.GetAllKeys().Contains("AzureAdB2C"))
        {
            var debugMode = host.AppSettings.Get(nameof(HostConfig.DebugMode), false);
            var azureSettings = host.AppSettings.Get<AzureAdB2COptions>("AzureAdB2C");
            var jwt = azureSettings.GetB2CJWTProviderReader(debugMode);

            jwt.PopulateSessionFilter = (session, payload, request) =>
            {
                if (session.Email == null && payload.ContainsKey("upn") && payload["upn"].Contains("@"))
                    session.Email = payload["upn"];
                if (session.UserName == null && payload.ContainsKey("unique_name"))
                    session.UserName = payload["unique_name"];
            };

            authProviders.Add(jwt);
        }

        var auth = new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), authProviders.ToArray())
        {
            HtmlRedirect = "/account/signin",
            HtmlLogoutRedirect = "/account/signout",
            IncludeAssignRoleServices = false,
            IncludeRegistrationService = false
        };

        // remove default service authentication services
        auth.ServiceRoutes.Remove(typeof(AuthenticateService));

        host.Plugins.Add(auth);
    }
```

We are using swagger as well to call the API (which works as expected).  This question is more about that requests that are submitted with a bearer token.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this existing answer for examples of how to validate why a [3rd Party JWT Token is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66949163/85785) with ServiceStack's JWT Auth Provider.

Comment: thanks mythz.  Any idea where in the pipeline i can add these additional statements that would help me debug the issue?  I tried putting a breakpoint into a service constructor, but i'm not getting any joy.  Is there anywhere in the apphost.cs file that i could do this, even if it allows me to inspect some values via a callback

Comment: @ossentoo In a separate C# App or unit test to see if you can identify why one of the JWT Issued Tokens is not validating.